# Emacs in batch mode: function on buffer does not give the expected result

Tags: terminal, emacs

The terminal command

> emacs --batch  --eval "
> (dolist (file command-line-args-left)
> (with-current-buffer (find-file-noselect file) (progn (princ
> (current-buffer)) (count-lines-page))  )  )
> "
> filename.org

gives

> "Page has 0 lines (0 + 0) filename.org"

as answer. In Emacs, the correct answer is given (as the file has lines). I am struggling to understand why. The same applies to other functions like org-lint. In addition, the ordering is not as defined by progn: "filename.org" is printed before the answer. I wonder if that is connected.
(Emacs 28.1)

Comment: Works for me if I remove the extra closing parenthesis. Please post complete instructions to reproduce the problem, including a sample `.org` file and a command that works with `emacs -Q …`.

Comment: Indeed, it works. Thank you. I had given the wrong path to the file. Sorry for that. I should have checked that some hours before... but I was sure that the path is correct